# IP security cam cannot connect to web interface

Tags: interface, ip-camera, referenceerror

I seek for help with my **MAGINON IPC-25HDC** camera.

I have set up this IP security camera on my local network but it seems like I cannot connect to the web interface anymore*.

Here are the recommended steps in order to connect to the website:

- access it via the IP address and port 80 by default (mine is `192.168.1.21:80` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwRHR.png)
- write `admin` as the user name
- do not write any password because the default settings does not specify any
- click on the "Login" button

I opened the network tab from the Developer Tools and whenever I give it a wrong password, I successfully receive a *401 Unauthorized* code ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnJxy.png)). But when I give it the right password (so obviously, nothing), it

- successfully returns a *200 OK* code ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYM2e.png))
- errors out with the following code *after the AJAX request is done*:

```js
common.js:350 Uncaught ReferenceError: pri is not defined
    at ipcStatusCom._endUserStatus (common.js:350)
    at Object.<anonymous> (common.js:23)
    at o (common.js:20)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (common.js:20)
    at w (common.js:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d (common.js:20)
```

I cannot fix this myself which is why I am here! Any help appreciated <3

---

* *I already did log in once to change the password as mentioned in the manual. Since then, no more. So I decided to factory-reset it. But I still cannot connect to it.*